# couldn't show submenu of horizontal menu on hover

Tags: html, css, flexbox

there are navigation panel(div id=#nav) in which is located horizontal menu(nav_main_ul). It has submenu. When I load site main horizontal is appear but on hover submenu of main manu is not appear.
I write:

```
   .nav_main_ul li a:hover .submenu{
         top:150;
 }
```

What is wrong?
Everything did work while I use flexbox for sidebar, content and footer.
I'm newbie in html and css. I think reason of failure is conflict between position(absolute, relative) and flexbox.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#nav {
  left: 0;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: #00004d;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_main_ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0 0 400px;
}

#nav ul {
  height: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #00004d;
}

#nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.nav_main_ul li a:hover {
  background: #000080;
}


/*.nav_main_ul li a:hover .submenu{
     top:50;
    }*/

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  top: -9999em;
}

.submenu li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #00004d;
}

.submenu li a {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}

.submenu li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

li:hover .submenu li {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="nav_main_ul">
    <li><a href="">Main</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">News</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show this as a working example with codepen.io.

Comment: Geuis, I added image above. Mawby you want full html and css code?

Comment: Need to see a working example. An image doesn't do that.

Comment: Geuis, https://codepen.io/delphi159/pen/dKNJEx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

Hi Delphi - To answer your question about the `+` selector, let's take a look at your HTML markup:

```
<li>
  <a href="">Main</a>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

We need to understand that in the above markup, we can express it as:

```
LI (Parent / Root)
 - A (Child of LI, Sibling of UL)
 - UL (Child of LI, Sibling of A)
   - LI (Child of UL, Grand-Child of LI)
```

Your desired action is that when a user `hover`s over the `A`, we show the `UL`.

USUALLY with CSS, we think of `NESTED` (or PARENT/CHILD) use-cases. But in YOUR use case, the `A` and `UL` are NOT in a parent/child relationship. Rather, they are siblings.

So, what we want is: When a user hovers over the `A`, we want the SIBLING(s) of A (in this case, only UL) to have `TOP: 50PX`.

There are TWO sibling selectors in CSS, "Adjacent" and "General". Adjacent means that it will ONLY apply when the siblings are directly together. For example:

```
<div>
    <p></p>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <p></p>
</div>

OR:

DIV
 - P
 - SPAN
 - SPAN 
 - P
```

Let's assume in the above, we wanted to select every SPAN that is a SIBLING of P. If we did:

```
p + span { color : red }
```

Only the FIRST span would be applied. That's because, it's the only span that immediately is next to a P element. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ucq5pg13/

What if we wanted ALL spans following a P to be red? That's where our GENERAL sibling selector comes into play:

```
p ~ span { color: red }
```

What this says is that ANY span that's a SIBLING of P, that comes AFTER IT, will be red.

It's important to note that it MUST come after. For example:

```
p ~ span { color: red }

<div>
    <span></span> <!-- I WOULD NOT BE RED -->
    <p></p>
    <span></span> <!-- I WOULD BE RED -->
    <span></span> <!-- I WOULD BE RED -->
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kb7n5236/

Hopefully that helps :)

**Original:**

When you `hover` over the `a` link, you'll need to position the `.submenu`. You can do something like:

```
<!-- On hover, show submenu -->
.nav_main_ul li a:hover + .submenu,
.nav_main_ul li a + .submenu:hover {
    top: 50px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1us0q4m3/1/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#nav {
  left: 0;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: #00004d;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_main_ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0 0 400px;
}

#nav ul {
  height: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #00004d;
}

#nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.nav_main_ul li a:hover {
  background: #000080;
}

  
.nav_main_ul li a:hover + .submenu,
.nav_main_ul li a + .submenu:hover {
    top: 50px;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  top: -9999em;
}

.submenu li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #00004d;
}

.submenu li a {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}

.submenu li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

li:hover .submenu li {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="nav_main_ul">
    <li><a href="">Main</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">News</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Jack, it warks. thank you. :) 
but what means symbol "+"  in  ".nav_main_ul li a:hover + .submenu" ?

Comment: @Delphi159, the `+` selector is an adjacent `sibling` selector, instead of a `child` selector. Here's an MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors :)

Comment: Jack, excuse me,can you shortly explain me meaning  of this code on English  in my case:.nav_main_ul li a:hover + .submenu
"It means that when I hover over the 'a' link do what...?"

Comment: @Delphi159 - Sure - I've updated my answer with a short explanation of how adjacent sibling selector is being used for your use case (and with some information about another sibling selector, the `~` (or general) selector) - Hope it helps :)

Comment: Jack, It's clear! thank you very much. Unfortunately I haven't enough reputation(<15) to vote for you answer. :)

Comment: Thanks @Delphi159 and no problem!! :) Good luck with the rest of your project!